# LightInject and automatic property instantiation

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Some time ago I worked on a project that I THINK used LightInject.  I no longer have access, so I can't just go look for myself.  It seemed like once the ServiceContainer was instantiated, something triggered reflection across all assemblies, and any properties of a certain interface type were automatically instantiated.  Something like this:

*A C# class library that contains a logger class; the logger is what should be injected.*

```
namespace Common {
    public interface ILogger { void Log(string msg); }

    public class Logger : ILogger {
        public Logger() { }
        public void Log(string msg) { Console.WriteLine(msg); }
    }
}
```

*A C# console app that references the class library.  Some things that didn't seem to help are commented out.*

```
namespace TestLightInject {
    class Program {
        private static ServiceContainer container;
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            container = new ServiceContainer();
            //container.EnableAnnotatedPropertyInjection();
            container.Register<ILogger, Logger>();
            //container.RegisterPropertyDependency<ILogger>((factory, propertyInfo) => new Logger());

            var worker = new Worker();
            worker.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class Worker {
        //[Inject]
        ILogger logger { get; set; } = null;  // THIS IS THE PROPERTY THAT NEEDS TO BE SET
        public Worker() { }
        public void DoSomething() { logger.Log("It works!"); }
    }
}
```

I guess I could allow public access to the service container, and change the Worker ctor to something like

```
public Worker() { logger = Program.container.GetInstance<ILogger>(); }
```

but it was simpler when any ILogger property was automatically instantiated.

Is there a way to do this with LightInject, or was it some other DI framework that did it?  Or am I just imagining it all?

Comment: Be careful with that last line because that's using the service locator pattern, which can appear to be similar to dependency injection but definitely isn't. What you need to do read up on DI best practices and research libraries. SO doesn't do library / external resource recommendations, so do some research, pick a DI library, take a shot at it, and then ask a question if you run into a problem.

Comment: I'm always careful.  But the whole point of this questions is to NOT do what's in that last line.  I'm not doing DI for the sake of doing DI because it's cool, I'm doing it because I need some objects injected in certain places.  DI is usually expressed in terms of ctor or method injection, which is often impractical for a project of significant size.  Carry a reference down thru 15 call levels just so it can be injected in the object that needs it?  Add ctor injectors to 500 or 1000 classes?  Let's not be ridiculous.  What I need is reflective injection....

Comment: So, yes, I did some research, I picked a DI library (LightInject), took a shot at it (multiple shots, actually), ran into a problem, and asked a question.  In case the main question wasn't clear, it's this: is there a way to get LightInject to do reflective injection?  It appeared that it was doing so in a project I no longer have access to.  Extensive googling has not turned up an answer.  I'm not looking for a recommendation, just an answer to the question, can library X do Y?